# Does QT 4.3 force you to subclass QThread?

Tags: qt

In QT 4.7 I could instantiate a new QThread and just move my object to the thread. However, in QT 4.3, it is complaining about QThread run() being pure virtual which I can't instantiate it? Was this changed from 4.3 in newer versions?

If this is the case how do I move my Object to the sublassed QThread using my required signals and slots?

Comment: Can't you simple have your object derive from QThread?

Comment: I'll try it, I wonder if signals and slots would still work if it isn't derived from Qobject?

Comment: And you are stuck with Qt 4.3? Anyway, just sublass it and add the missing pieces.

Comment: QThread derives from QObject. So there's no problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was this changed from 4.3 in newer versions?

Yes, at least, from Qt 4.8 it was changed.

Check the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#run

> The starting point for the thread. After calling start(), the newly created thread calls this function. **The default implementation simply calls exec()**.
>
> If this is the case how do I move my Object to the sublassed QThread using my required signals and slots?

`QThread` derives itself from `QObject`, so simply derove from `QThread` instead of `QObject`. You signals will work.

Note that you may need to deal with the fourth hidden parameter of `connect` function when connecting slots and signals. This parameters specifies connection behaviour in case of multi-threaded program.